# Why does my bash script not cd correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bash-scripting

I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux, and learning the terminal. I want to open applications on my desktop with the terminal, so I decided to make a bash script to `cd` to the `.exe` file and run it.

This is what I have:

```
cd "/mnt/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/'Opera GX'/"
./launcher.exe
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
./operaLaunch.sh: line 1: cd: $'/mnt/Users/akaza/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera GX/\r': No such file or directory
./operaLaunch.sh: line 2: ./launcher.exe: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why the line 1 is different in the error message.

Edit: So, I downloaded Notepad++ and changed the line endings to the proper Unix ones, but still not getting the script to work. Also, yes, I had a typo in the quoting of my script. This is how my script looks now

```
cd "/mnt/c/Users/akaza/AppData/Local/Programs/'Opera GX'/"
./launcher.exe
```

This is the error message I get now:

```
./operaLaunch.sh: line 1: cd: /mnt/c/Users/akaza/AppData/Local/Programs/'Opera GX'/: No such file or directory
./operaLaunch.sh: line 2: ./launcher.exe: No such file or directory
```

Maybe the whitespace?

Comment: `"cd "/mnt/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera GX/"` has an odd number of double-quotes. that's rarely desirable. is your problematic command the same, or was this a typo while posting?

Comment: One question per question please. I answered your main question and removed the other one from the body of your post because it was too distinct. If you still need help with the other issue then ask a separate question.

Comment: See the Stackoverflow question ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for more info about this.

Comment: The path should start with `/mnt/c/Users` and there shouldn't be a quote before `cd`

Comment: You have added inner single-quotes. Are they in the path you want to `cd` to? I think the error message does not correspond with the command in its current form.

Comment: Again: are the single-quotes really in the path you want to `cd` to?

Comment: Well, the directory has a space in the name, so I wasn't sure how to write that in a bash script. I always used single quotes when I used cd to get there in the terminal since it wouldn't recognize the whitespace

Comment: But you have the outer double-quotes. Single-quotes in double-quotes stay literal and vice versa. Single- xor double-quotes that embrace the entire path (or even the space alone) should do. My (now deleted) answer had solved one problem, but you apparently introduced another one by injecting single-quotes that weren't there in the original question.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I misunderstood. Yep, after just putting the quotes over the whole path, it's working as intended. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to Kamil Maciorowski for helping me understand, the problem was with the inclusion of the single-quotes inside of the double-quotes. After removing the single-quotes, my script is working as intended. Thanks for the help